# Как сверстать на БЭМ первые буквы слова?

Tags: html, css, бэм

В БЭМ не используют селекторы тегов и идентификаторов. Стили блоков и элементов описываются через селекторы классов. Как тогда сверстать первые буквы у слова? Неужели каждой первой букве задавать отдельный класс элемента? Задал через `span`, но по методологии БЭМ это не верно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<!-- header -->

    <header class="header">
        <div class="wrapper">

            <div class="top">
                <div class="top__title"><span>S</span>ublime</div>
                <div class="top__description"><span>S</span>ublime: A one page responsive wordpress theme suitable for any kind of business representation.</div>
                <div class="top__link">Download the psd.</div>
            </div>

            <div class="banner">
                <div class="banner__title"><span>We</span> create Awesome Games</div>
                <div class="nav">
                    <div class="nav__item"><a class="nav__link" href="#">About</a></div>
                    <div class="nav__item"><a class="nav__link" href="#">Development</a></div>
                    <div class="nav__item"><a class="nav__link" href="#">Projects</a></div>
                    <div class="nav__item"><a class="nav__link" href="#">Blog</a></div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </header>

    <!-- header -->
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
p span:first-child {
  color: red;
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<p><span>Текст</span><span> и это тоже текст</span></p>
```

Comment: Я спрашивал, как это реализовать на классах по БЭМ. Там есть не первая буква, а первое слово.